# Problem solving for linear algebra's matrix R

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

i found "U" but failed to find "R". 
What I did is add row3 to row2, then divide by pivots, which gave me my "R".

i thought that;s how its done, why did i fail it. How is it done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You left out a pivot.  You should have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank-u so much, i had actually not seen that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reduced row echelon form requires that the pivots (the left-most non-zero entry of every row) must be 1.  In $U$, you already have this in the bottom row. All that is needed is to divide the top row by 3.

Comment: thanks, i realized i had made a mistake